# Nudge axis ticks / axis breaks vertically in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I vertically adjust the axis ticks on the y-axis? In the example below how could I move the up to match with the text?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_point(position = position_nudge(y = .1)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(vjust = -2.3))
```

[image: ggplot axis ticks not aligned]

Comment: this is just a reproducible in example -- in my real data my y-axis is discrete and I'm adjusting my points as well

Comment: Probably the easiest is not to shift the ticks, but to shift your data - nudge the ys or the xs a certain amount, and there you have your shift.

Comment: @Tjebo, i don't think the categorical data would change the how the code is written? As I previously stated, in my real data I have nudged the data already and I want it to correspond with the axis

Comment: (the reason i wanted the nudge in the first place is because i have a left and right discrete y-axis, and I wanted to distinguish between the two more efficiently)

Comment: @Tjebo i updated the example

Comment: I don't think it is possible without some diligent effort to set continuous position breaks for a discrete y-axis. I'd recommend  switching to a continuous axis that you can label as a discrete axis.

Comment: so in my real data i am doing this -- using a "continuous" axis with discrete labels / breaks. In this example I am indifferent about what kind of axis the answers use

Comment: Can you post at least some part of your data?  It's quite difficult to see how to adjust in your case.  To "fix" the case above seems to have a different solution compared to your own case.  I would be that if you have to nudge your own data to fit into a particular format, the answer may not be to fix the result of that adjustment, but to find another way to get what you want *without adjusting/nudging in the first place*.